# Template scoping issue code wont compile

Tags: c++, binary-tree

My problem is that i get this error

```
binarytree.cpp: In member function ‘void BinaryTree<T>::printPaths(const BinaryTree<T>::Node*) const [with T = int]’:
binarytree.cpp:88:   instantiated from ‘void BinaryTree<T>::printPaths() const [with T = int]’
main.cpp:113:   instantiated from ‘void printTreeInfo(const BinaryTree<T>&, const std::string&, const std::string&) [with T = int]’
main.cpp:47:   instantiated from here
binarytree.cpp:116: error: passing ‘const BinaryTree<int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void BinaryTree<T>::findPaths(BinaryTree<T>::Node*, int*, int) [with T = int]’ discards qualifiers
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I understand that it could be the template that is causing scope issues I dont want it to think that Node member variable of the BinaryTree class How do I accomplish this?

```
// printPaths()
    template <typename T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::printPaths() const
    {
        printPaths(root);

    }
    template <typename T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::printPath(int path[],int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            cout << (char)path[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::findPaths(Node * subroot, int path[], int pathLength)
    {
        if(subroot == NULL) return;
        path[pathLength] = subroot->elem;
        pathLength++;
        if(subroot->left == NULL && subroot->right = NULL)
            printPath(path,pathLength);
            else
            {
                findPaths(subroot->left, path, pathLength);
                findPaths(subroot->right,path,pathLength);
            }
    }
    template<typename T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::printPaths(const Node* subroot) const
    {
        int path[100];
        findPaths(subroot,path,0);
    }
```

Comment: You did not post the error, only *where* the error appears. Add the actual error to the post (hint, copy a few lines, not just the two)

Comment: When replying to people you should add @*username* to notify them of the reply - for instance @DavidRodríguez-dribeas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `findPaths()` (non-`const` member) from `printPaths()` (`const` member) function. **Calling non-*const* member from *const* member is not allowed** by C++.

You have to re-write the code by either making both `printPaths()` as non-const methods or `findPaths()` and `printPath()` as `const` methods.

Comment: any insight on how i can do that?

Comment: @user949358: Just add a `const` at the far right of the `printPaths()` and `findPath` methods (you might also need to make some of the other arguments `const`, like `const Node* subroot`, as you will not be able to pass the `root` member to the method otherwise. (As a matter of fact, you should tag all member methods that do not modify the object as `const` by default, fixing const-correctness after the fact is usually more painful than writing const-correct code from the beginning)